# Inserting default data she user signup with secure social

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

When a user signup on my system, I want that some data be insert on the database (default data, sample data).

I did this on the method save of the UserService plugin. It's working, but the problem that I'm facing is that the language of the user is not available, so when I use the Messages API to translate the sample data it always translate to the default language.

I've tried adding the implicit to the save method but that broke the trait (in Scala case) and on Java the same thing. (Yes, I'he tried to do writing Java and Scala UserPlugin even not knowing Scala).

How can I do this? Is there any way that I can get the user language on the save method? Or there is another place that it would be better doing this?

Comment: do you want to know user browser default language?

Comment: Yes. I wan't to know the default language... or inside all the languages that the user accepts, the first one that I support.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that i understand your question. but you can get user's browser's default language on request at controller by

```
if (request.acceptLanguages.size > 0) {
   val lang = request.acceptLanguages(0).code
   //assgin user language to PLAY_LANG(cookies)

   Redirect("/").withLang(play.api.i18n.Lang(lang)) 
}
```

now there is a cookie in user's browser from where you can get the user language

`request.acceptLanguages` will returns the list of all accepted languages by the user's browser

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the Request available. The controller is implemented by the SecureSocial API and it executes a code that is implemented by me (the UserService). And the API doesn't send's the request to the UserService.